# Разбиение строки по регулярному выражению

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Здравствуйте!

Входной формат строки такой: различное количество `string` (через пробелы) пробел 3 `int`-а (через пробелы). Мне нужно разбить эту строки на две, в одной `string`-и, во второй `int`-ы.

Знаю, что в Java для этого есть метод `split`, но я не знаю, какое регулярное выражение нужно поставить в параметры. Подскажите, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как решить Вашу задачу именно методом `split` не знаю, но можно чуть-чуть по-другому:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\D]*) ([\\d]* [\\d]* [\\d]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
m.find();
String sStr = m.group(1);
String iStr = m.group(2);
```

В итоге, `sStr` – строка со словами, `iStr` – строка с числами.

На всякий случай можете проверять результат работы метода `m.find()`, который возвращает `true`, если совпадение найдено и `false` в противном случае.

Можно еще проще – `([\D]*) ([\d ]*)`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это именно то, что мне было нужно. Немного не понимаю суть регулярного выражения, но с этим уже буду разбираться сам.

Comment: Подскажите, в результирующей строке останутся пробелы?

Comment: @HatmZull, Да, останутся.